# Why was Hiou and Kanae's meeting omitted in Skip Beat anime?

Tags: skip-beat

Skip Beat in manga and anime are closely identical, (meaning, what was shown in the manga was shown in the anime during the first part) until such time when Kanae met Hiou.

I watched the anime first before I read the manga so I was shocked at Hiou's appearance (since he was just shown in the ending of the anime).

What was covered in the anime was covered in the manga, except for Hiou and Kanae's meeting. In the anime, after Kyoko successfully finished her PV with Shou (Stage 19: The Last Ritual), the next episode (Stage 20: Invitation to the Moon) is where she was scouted for an upcoming drama.

While in the manga, Kanae and Hiou's meeting happened between those said anime episodes. Why was that part skipped or omitted in the anime?

Is there any particular reason for this or did the production decided to not to include it in the anime since Kanae and Hiou's meeting isn't that significant to the main plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of things that are in the manga aren't shown in the anime, so they must have thought it wasn't important enough later on.
Usually the reason for this is that there isn't enough time for it in the stated amount of episodes given to the director. Or you could say that there isn't enough budget.
The Skip Beat anime series was also ended and not continued, probably because of lack of popularity or budget.

On [myanimelist.net](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=438975), a user asked the original director of the anime series if it would be continued. The director would like to but states that there has to be a big amount of popularity for the series to continue. This makes me conclude that apparently the anime wasn't popular enough, which is strange because the manga has a huge amount of followers. But usually a manga series has more readers than the anime has watchers, due to more chances for manga to be published than for anime.
Also on the [wikipedia page for anime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime) it says:

> anime became more accepted in the mainstream in Japan
>   (although less than manga)

This is also a reason why some manga series are continued while their anime counterpart is not.